# What is the difference between this Ruby and shell code?

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a shell-script calculating the CPU-usage in percent.
As I want to extend the functionality, and want to do this in Ruby instead of calling the shell script from Ruby.

I tried to rewrite the code in Ruby, but there are differences in the final output.

The shell codes output is between 5% and 10%, and the Ruby code's output is between 97.5% and 97.8%.

This is the Ruby code:

```
result = `cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '`.split(" ")
result.delete("cpu")
idle_time0 = result[4].to_i
total_time0 = 0

result.each do |partial_time|
  total_time0 += partial_time.to_i
end


sleep 0.5


result = `cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '`.split(" ")
result.delete("cpu")
idle_time = result[4].to_i
total_time = 0

result.each do |partial_time|
  total_time += partial_time.to_i
end

diff_idle = idle_time - idle_time0
diff_total = total_time - total_time0

diff_usage = (1000*(diff_total - diff_idle)/(diff_total+5).to_f)/10.0

p diff_usage
```

This is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CPU=(`cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '`) # Get the total CPU statistics.
unset CPU[0]                          # Discard the "cpu" prefix.
IDLE=${CPU[4]}                        # Get the idle CPU time.

# Calculate the total CPU time.
TOTAL=0
for VALUE in "${CPU[@]}"; do
  let "TOTAL=$TOTAL+$VALUE"
done

# Remember the total and idle CPU times for the next check.
PREV_TOTAL="$TOTAL"
PREV_IDLE="$IDLE"

# Wait before checking again.
sleep 0.5

CPU=(`cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '`) # Get the total CPU statistics.
unset CPU[0]                          # Discard the "cpu" prefix.
IDLE=${CPU[4]}                        # Get the idle CPU time.

# Calculate the total CPU time.
TOTAL=0
for VALUE in "${CPU[@]}"; do
  let "TOTAL=$TOTAL+$VALUE"
done

# Calculate the CPU usage since we last checked.
let "DIFF_IDLE=$IDLE-$PREV_IDLE"
let "DIFF_TOTAL=$TOTAL-$PREV_TOTAL"
let "DIFF_USAGE=(1000*($DIFF_TOTAL-$DIFF_IDLE)/$DIFF_TOTAL+5)/10"

echo -en "\rCPU: $DIFF_USAGE%  \b\b"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGNOMmers already pointed out your indexing error, but I'd like to note that translating into ruby as you've done has had almost no benefit.  Your ruby code reads as ugly as bash and you're still shelling out twice to acquire `/proc/stat`.  You can make this more readable, less error prone, and more efficient by using ruby as the high level language it is.

Here's a sample re-write. I've made a little method to turn the /proc/stat lines into a struct with meaningful names, so no more array indexing problems can crop in and it's always clear which timer value you're referencing. I've use [`File::readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines) and [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to read the proc filesystem without having to shell out. I used printf formatting to get the percentile rounding effect you seemed to be looking for.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html
CpuTimes = Struct.new :user, :nice, :system, :idle, :iowait, :irq,
                      :softirq, :steal, :guest, :guest_nice, :total

def get_cpu_times
  parts = File.readlines('/proc/stat').grep(/^cpu /).first.split
  times = parts[1..-1].map(&:to_i)
  CpuTimes[ *times ].tap { |r| r[:total] = times.reduce(:+) }
end

c0 = get_cpu_times
sleep 0.5
c1 = get_cpu_times

idle  = c1.idle - c0.idle
total = c1.total - c0.total
usage = total - idle
printf "CPU: %.1f%%", 100.0 * usage / total
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in bash unsetting an array value produces weird effects:

```bsh
CPU=(`cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu '`) # Get the total CPU statistics.

let COUNT=0
while [ $COUNT -lt "${#CPU[@]}" ]; do
  echo "value at $COUNT: ${CPU[$COUNT]}"
  let "COUNT=$COUNT+1"
done

unset CPU[0]                          # Discard the "cpu" prefix.

let COUNT=0
while [ $COUNT -lt "${#CPU[@]}" ]; do
  echo "value at $COUNT: ${CPU[$COUNT]}"
  let "COUNT=$COUNT+1"
done
```

This outputs:

```
value at 0: cpu
value at 1: 763993
value at 2: 116443
value at 3: 179513
value at 4: 22344343
value at 5: 536446
value at 6: 5
value at 7: 640
value at 8: 0
value at 9: 0
value at 10: 0
value at 0:          # This should be 763993
value at 1: 763993   # and so on...
value at 2: 116443
value at 3: 179513
value at 4: 22344343
value at 5: 536446
value at 6: 5
value at 7: 640
value at 8: 0
value at 9: 0        # ...and the last 0 value is vanished!
```

Anyway, the solution is to decrement the ruby idle_time index:

```ruby
...
idle_time0 = result[3].to_i
...
idle_time = result[3].to_i
...
```